# Reading a txt file in url into BeautifulSOUP

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some url address that is to a txt file, which contians html code. This is a sample link:

http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/70858/000119312507058027/0001193125-07-058027.txt

I want to read this html code with BeautifulSoup with such a code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 

url =    "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/70858/000119312507058027/0001193125-07-058027.txt"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
print (soup.prettify())
```

However, I got a lot of errors like:

`File "C:/Users/.../aa.py", line 7, in <module> print (soup.prettify())
       File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bs4\element.py", line 1097, in prettify
       return self.decode(True, formatter=formatter)`

I am suspicous that it happens because the url is to a txt file not a html. Am i right? If so, can someone let me know what is the solution here?

Comment: You are right. BeautifulSoup is used specifically to handle html and xml files. If you just want plain text, that should be located in the variable you called `page`. Try `print page` to confirm the text you want is there.

Comment: Thanks a lot @eigenchris! Yes the page is there, but since I want to extract some tables from that kind of code, I need to get it somehow into bs. do you have any recommendations on that?

Comment: You could delete everything that isn't between the `<html>` and `</html>` tags. From there you would have a valid html file you could parse with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try just feeding the HTML section of the text file (from the  tag) into Beautiful soup, I imagine its breaking because the start of the text file doesn't contain any HTML.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can you please be a little more specific what do you mean by feeding the html section? how can I do that? sorry for my ignorance!

Comment: Do some parsing on the string before you pass it into BeatifulSoup. For example, instead of just passing the whole text document, just give it section from `<DOCUMENT>` to `</DOCUMENT>`

Comment: Try skipping the first few lines of text

Comment: What you're really trying to do is get the html section out of the text document (as at the moment, BeautifulSoup has no idea what to do with it)

Comment: an example would have been useful